# How to connect devices behind Comcast router/modem with devices behind wireless router

Tags: routing, ip, subnet, modem

I know this is going to seem like a simple solution but I have been unable to find a clear answer through Google.

Simple office setup: I have a Comcast modem/router that has 4 hard wired ports. In one of those ports I have a Cisco wireless router which also has 4 of its own ports. What is the method for getting devices behind the modem/router to ping/communicate with devices behind the wireless router?

They are all on the same subnet but the IP ranges differ. The router produces 192.168.1.1 by default while the Comcast modem/router produces 10.1.10.1 by default.

I think what I'm attempting to do might be considered "extending" the modem/router's network but I'm not sure.

Comment: You have created a [double NAT](http://graemenoble.id.au/post/48695277030/double-nat-explained-and-possible-solutions) situation. See [David's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/551784/32986) for one possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log into the wireless router and disable its DHCP server.
2. Connect the wireless router to one of the cable modem/router's **LAN** ports.
3. Do not use the wireless router's Internet/WAN port. (It's not connected to the Internet, it's connected to the LAN.)

You now have one big happy LAN produced by the Comcast modem/router. You may need to reboot devices connected to the wireless router to get them to request new IP addresses from the modem/router.